# How can I get insert id of bulk flush in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I get All Insert Ids from bulk insert data ?
My code as is Below :

```
 foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $subDocument = new SubDocument();
        $subDocument->setUrl($url);
        $subDocument->setParentDocument($parentDocument);
        $dm->persist($subDocument);
    }
    $dm->flush();
    $dm->clear();
```

Now How Can I get those insert Ids of records ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `Subdocument`'s ID after `$dm->flush();`, therefore you have to keep `Subdocument`s instances to retrieve their ids after flush.

```
 $subDocuments = array(); // init array
 foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $subDocument = new SubDocument();
    $subDocument->setUrl($url);
    $subDocument->setParentDocument($parentDocument);
    $subDocuments[] = $subDocument; //added to array
    $dm->persist($subDocument);
}
$dm->flush();
//now you can access IDs iterating $subDocuments like:
foreach($subDocuments as $subDocument) {
    echo $subDocument->getId();
}
```